# Working with means and variances

Tags: simplifying-expressions, probability-or-statistics, series-expansion, sequence

My goal is to work out on the following equation:

$$Mean(P)(1-Mean (P))\left (h + (1 - 2 h) (1 - \frac {Var (P)} {Mean (P) (1 - Mean (P))}) (1 - 
      Mean (P)) + \frac {Var (P)} {Mean (P) (1 - Mean (P))} (1 - 
      h) \right)$$

where $P$ is a sample, $Mean(P)$ is the `Mean` value of the sample $P$: $Mean(P) = 1/n \sum_{i=1}^n p_i$. $Var(P)$ is the `Variance` of the random variable $P$.

How can I `Simplify` this kind of equation with *Mathematica*?

I thought I could eventually define a sequence of $p_i$ of undefined length and work with it. Is something similar feasible?

Here is the *Mathematica* code:

```
Mean[P](1-Mean[P])( h + (1-2h)(1-(Variance[P])/(Mean[P](1-Mean[P])))*
  (1-Mean[P]) + (Variance[P])/(Mean[P](1-Mean[P])) (1-h))
```

Comment: @Öskå Thanks for your comment. As I don't really know how to treat this kind of calculation I don't really know what code to write. But I added edited my question. Hope that makes sense. I realize that when running `Simplify[..]` on my expression I get a result! Maybe that was all I wanted. But if I run `Simplify[Mean[X^2]-Mean[X]^2]` Mathematica does not answer `Var[X]`. Thanks for your help

Comment: I am confused by several aspects of the question. First, you say $Exp[P]$ is the expected value of $P$, but you then define it as the sample mean (which is not the same thing). Second, your sample mean is defined as the sum from 0 to $n$ (i.e. $n+1$ values), but you divide by $n$, not $n+1$. Doesn't make sense. Third, you then define $Var[P]$ as the population variance, but do you actually want it to be that, or the sample variance? And if the latter, which definition of sample variance:  $1/n$ or  $1/(n-1)$ ?

Comment: @wolfies Thanks your comment helps. Yes, I actually talk about sample mean and variance not about statistical moments, you're correct. And moreover I made the mistake in defining it! I edited the question to fix this mistake.

Comment: @Remi.b If you define `P = Symbol["p" <> ToString@#] & /@ Range@10`, what result would you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `FullSimplify` we obtain

```
fun0[P_,h_] := Mean[P]*(1 - Mean[P])*(h + (1 - 2 h) (1 - (Variance[P])/(Mean[P] (1 - Mean[P])))*
  (1 - Mean[P]) + (Variance[P])/(Mean[P](1 - Mean[P])) (1 - h))
fun[P_,h_] := FullSimplify@fun0[P]
fun[P,h]
```

> ```
> -(-1 + Mean[P]) Mean[P] (1 - h + (-1 + 2 h) Mean[P]) + 
>   (h + Mean[P] - 2 h Mean[P]) Variance[P]
> ```

Declare variables to see if the simplified equation is the same

```
P = {1, 2, 3};
h = 1;
fun0[P,h]
```

> ```
> -5
> ```

as does

```
fun[P,h]
```

> ```
> -5
> ```